# Create a directory when a file has a similar name

Tags: directory

I'm using ivy-mode and when I try and make a directory and it has the same sort of name as an autocomplete then the directory will not be made.

eg:
if I have webapp.pdf and I want to create a directory called webapp then autocomplete kicks in and thinks I want to call it webapp.pdf and then doesn't create the directory as it has the same name as a file. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using <kbd>C-M-j</kbd>, as explained [here](https://github.com/abo-abo/swiper#frequently-asked-questions)

> Q: How do I enter an input that matches one of the candidates instead
>   of this candidate? Example: create a file bar when a file barricade
>   exists in the current directory.
>
> A: Press C-M-j. Alternatively, you can make the prompt line selectable
>   with (setq ivy-use-selectable-prompt t).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. If you append a forward slash (`/`) after your directory name, `ivy-mode` will be forced to treat it as a directory path.